Application of Arzelá-Ascoli theorem
For a uni assignment I am asked the following

For some open and bounded $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$, prove that the embedding of Hölder space
$$C^{0,\beta}(\bar\Omega) \hookrightarrow C(\bar\Omega)$$
is compact using the Arzelá-Ascali Theorem.

The Arzelá-Ascoli theorem is formulated as

Let $(X, )$ be a metric space, $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $u_n :X → R$ be point-wise bounded and equicontinuous. Then it holds true that $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded and contains a uniformly bounded subsequence.

Where I (immediately) get stuck is that I dont see how the theorem is supposed to be applied when talking about Hölder spaces as a whole, much less how it could be used to prove compactness.
Any help at all in helping me towards a solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

If $M$ is a bounded subset of a Hoelder space, then it is a bounded and equicontinuous subset of space of continuous functions.

@daw do you know how you could prove this from the theorem in the given formulation?

Your formulation of the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem is not quite right. One way to fix this is to require that $X$ is compact and also that $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence, not simply a uniformly bounded subsequence.
Here is a rough outline of an approach. That the embedding is compact is equivalent to showing that every sequence in
\begin{equation}
\{f\in C^{0, \beta}(\overline{\Omega}) : \|f\|_{C^{0, \beta}} \leq 1 \} \tag{$*$}
\end{equation}
has a subsequence converging in $C(\overline{\Omega})$. Since the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem is a result that characterises compactness in $C(\overline{\Omega })$, it is reasonable to attempt applying that result to the collection ($*$). Now you need to check that the assumptions of the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem are met. Once you write out the definition of what it means for a function to belong to $C^{0, \beta}(\overline{\Omega})$ it should be clear what to do from there.
